# How to include comments inside text to be processed by spaCy

Tags: spacy

I'm using spaCy v2 with the French module `fr_core_news_sm`
Unfortunately this model produces many parsing errors so I would like to preprocess the text in order to optimize the output.

Here is an example: the interjection/adverb *carrément* is analyzed as the plural 3rd person of the (imaginary) verb *carrémer*. I don't mind for the wrong POS tag analysis, but it does spoil the dependency parse. Therefore I would like to replace carrément by some other adverb (like *souvent*) or interjection for which I know that spaCy will parse correctly.

For that I need to able to add a comment saying that a replacement has taken place, something like `souvent /*orig=carrément*/` so that `souvent` will be parsed by spaCy but NOT `/*orig=carrément*/` which will have no incidence on the dependency parsing.

Is this possible?

IS there some other way to tell spaCy “carrément is NOT a verb but an interjection please treat it as such”, without recompiling the model?

(I know this is possible in TreeTagger, where you can add a configuration file with POS tags for any word you want… but of course TreeTagger is not a dependency parser.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom extensions to save this kind of information on each token:

https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes

```
from spacy.tokens import Token
Token.set_extension("orig", default="")
doc[1]._.orig = "carrément"
```

Here's an example from the `Token` docs:

```
from spacy.tokens import Token
fruit_getter = lambda token: token.text in ("apple", "pear", "banana")
Token.set_extension("is_fruit", getter=fruit_getter)
doc = nlp("I have an apple")
assert doc[3]._.is_fruit
```

(The tagger and the dependency parser are completely independent, so changing the POS of a word won't affect how it gets parsed.)